# Subclass of DbContext: one overall or one per model?

Tags: asp.net-core

I am developing my first ASP.NET core app that does not follow a tutorial and also my first ASP.NET core app that has more than one class in its model. I thought I would need to create one subclass of `DbContext` for every model class. But now it seems that I need only one subclass of `DbContext` in the entire app. Is this correct?

`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should have one context per database. To be more explicit, you should have one context per subdomain of your application, which generally coincides with a database. However, in something like a microservices architecture, or just any DDD-style pattern, you'd essentially have a context per service, corresponding to each discreet slice of your domain.

In any case, you'd *never* employ a context per entity, as that would be virtually useless.